# Laravel WhereHas Query

Tags: laravel

I wanna get data which is `pwra_dt` = $month && $year. What can I do? For now, it shows all records!!

Query:

```
$purchaseOrder = PurchaseOrder::whereHas('pwra', function (Builder $query) use ($year, $month) {
    $query->whereYear('pwra_dt', $year)
        ->whereMonth('pwra_dt', $month);

})
->get();
```

PurchaseOrder(Model)

```
public function pwra()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Pwra', 'purchase_order_uuid', 'purchase_order_uuid');
}
```

PWRA (Model)

```
public function purchaseOrder()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\PurchaseOrder', 'purchase_order_uuid', 'purchase_order_uuid');
}
```

Comment: It shows all data from `PurchaseOrder` model? Need to know the `pwra_dt` table format

Comment: yes, it shows all data from purchaseOrder. pwra_dt format is Y-m-d

Comment: I think there are something wrong on whereYear , whereMonth query , try with `whereYear('pwra_dt', '2020`)` and `->whereMonth('pwra_dt', '01');` month should be 01 - 31

Comment: problem solved!!!